How can I get amplitude of audio playing in flutter?
dependencies used:
  audio_video_progress_bar: ^2.0.3
  just_audio: ^0.9.31
  audio_service: ^0.18.4
  on_audio_query: ^2.8.1

None of them helps to get amplitude of audio playing. I am looking to extract maxDecible and minDecible of audio.

just_audio has an experimental visualizer stream feature that you might be able to use for this purpose, though to use it you will have to pull directly from the visualizer branch on the project repo. Otherwise, what you are looking for is the ability to analyze the raw audio output stream, which to my knowledge, none of the off-the-shelf Flutter plugins support yet.
